# Giving Docker multiple containers unique public hostnames on a single Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, routing, docker

I'm looking to set up multiple Docker containers to serve different hostnames on a single machine, without the hassle of Kubernetes.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             STATUS              NAMES
673394ef1d4c        busybox             "top"               Up 45 seconds       nostalgic_shockley
d85756f57265        busybox             "top"               Up 51 seconds       high_albattani
```

Lets say I have some domain `xyz.com` ; I'd want `alpha.xyz.com` routing to `nostalgic_shockley` and `beta.xyz` routing to `high_albattani`.

I looked `/etc/hostname` and it has some local hostname.

```
root@saag:/home/root# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
...
root@saag:/home/root# cat /etc/hostname
saag
...
root@saag:/home/root# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I even tried assigning the hostnames to individual Docker ip addresses via `/etc/hostname` but I still couldn't reach the containers.

Also, in my domain management panel... should I simply be setting the a-record for `alpha.xyz.com` and `beta.xyz.com` to this host's IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think you are on the wrong track. The internal Docker network is not represented on the host's external network. The host will have to route traffic.

Usually you would want to allow connections from the outside world **to some service** (i.e. a tcp port in most cases) within the docker containers.

If you are talking about HTTP and want port 80 (or 443) for both containers it will not be as simple as routing a port from the external interface to them since you cannot forward it to both. So my preferred solution would be to have an Apache on the host machine doing name based virtual hosting with two vhosts for the two different DNS names and which forward the traffic to their respective Docker container.

BTW:
If you would have different ports to be mapped from the external network to the Docker containers, some simpler (network-based) methods would work, e.g. some iptables based forwarding or host port mappings.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, in my domain management panel... should I simply be setting the a-record for alpha.xyz.com and beta.xyz.com to this host's IP address?

The domain management panel is what you should *start with.* Neither Docker nor the containers themselves can make a subdomain out of nothing; it must be created within the DNS service provider first.

Once that's done, the Docker host can route packets to the correct container using whatever facilities Docker provides (iptables TCP/UDP port forwarding, I would assume) – or you can route HTTP requests using a reverse proxy.

You do not need to change the container hostnames for this to work.

---

*(Technically DNS does support dynamic registration within the protocol, but most service providers either do not support it at all, or require using their custom API instead of the standard DNS facilities.*

*On top of that, the machines would need to have a way to authenticate with the DNS provider, and there is no good universal system for that. As a result such automatic subdomain creation is almost exclusive to Active Directory in practice.)*